# Trailing Closures on generics?

Tags: swift

Hi I am trying to understand the following code from Alamofire. How can you initialise a struct with "`{}`" I know that you can call a closure with Trailing Closures. I know I am totally missing something, but what?

```
extension Request {
    public func responseObject<T: ResponseObjectSerializable>(completionHandler: Response<T, NSError> -> Void) -> Self {

        let responseSerializer = ResponseSerializer<T, NSError> { // What is this?
                request, response, data, error in
                guard error == nil else { return .Failure(error!) }

            let JSONResponseSerializer = Request.JSONResponseSerializer(options: .AllowFragments)
            let result = JSONResponseSerializer.serializeResponse(request, response, data, error)

            switch result {
            case .Success(let value):
                if let
                    response = response,
                    responseObject = T(response: response, representation: value)
                {
                    return .Success(responseObject)
                } else {
                    let failureReason = "JSON could not be serialized into response object: \(value)"
                    let error = Error.errorWithCode(.JSONSerializationFailed, failureReason: failureReason)
                    return .Failure(error)
                }
            case .Failure(let error):
                return .Failure(error)
            }
        }

        return response(responseSerializer: responseSerializer, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}
```

The struct ResponseSerializer from Alamofire

```
public struct ResponseSerializer<Value, Error: ErrorType>: ResponseSerializerType {
    /// The type of serialized object to be created by this `ResponseSerializer`.
    public typealias SerializedObject = Value

    /// The type of error to be created by this `ResponseSerializer` if serialization fails.
    public typealias ErrorObject = Error

    /**
        A closure used by response handlers that takes a request, response, data and error and returns a result.
    */
    public var serializeResponse: (NSURLRequest?, NSHTTPURLResponse?, NSData?, NSError?) -> Result<Value, Error>

    /**
        Initializes the `ResponseSerializer` instance with the given serialize response closure.

        - parameter serializeResponse: The closure used to serialize the response.

        - returns: The new generic response serializer instance.
    */
    public init(serializeResponse: (NSURLRequest?, NSHTTPURLResponse?, NSData?, NSError?) -> Result<Value, Error>) {
        self.serializeResponse = serializeResponse
    }
}
```

Comment: actually what do you want to know lol?

Comment: you wrote "How can you initialise a struct with {}  ?" No, You can not. {} type is ()->() By the way, I don't see where in the example code is that kind of initialization.

Comment: Consider the definition of `init`. It takes one parameter, a closure. So, that `let responseSerializer` line is using trailing closure syntax to supply the closure to `init`.

Comment: ... and that closure commence to be value of structure's property seralizeResponse (see Rob's answer )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question can be greatly pared down (and should have been). Here is the relevant declaration of ResponseSerializer:

```
public struct ResponseSerializer<Value, Error: ErrorType>: ResponseSerializerType {
    public init(serializeResponse: (NSURLRequest?, NSHTTPURLResponse?, NSData?, NSError?) -> Result<Value, Error>) {
        self.serializeResponse = serializeResponse
    }
}
```

So this initializer, `init(serializeResponse:)`, takes one parameter — a function taking four parameters and returning one parameter (of the specified types).

Thus, we can initialize like this:

```
func f (request:NSURLRequest?, response:NSHTTPURLResponse?, data:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Result<Value, Error>)  {
    guard error == nil else { return .Failure(error!) 
}
let responseSerializer = ResponseSerializer<T, NSError>(serializeResponse:f)
```

However, this can be condensed. We don't really need the function `f` for anything else, so we can supply it as an anonymous function; it doesn't need a name or a full declaration. Moreover, there is a "shortcut" rule for anonymous functions, that if an anonymous function is the *last* parameter to a function, it can be provided literally *after* the function's closing parentheses, with the parameter name omitted. And if the function takes no *other* parameters, *its parentheses can be omitted altogether*.

Well, this `init` is exactly such a function — it takes a function as its last (and only) parameter — so that is exactly what the code in question does:

```
let responseSerializer = ResponseSerializer<T, NSError> { 
    request, response, data, error in
    guard error == nil else { return .Failure(error!) 
}
```

Comment: For a full list of the anonymous function syntax shortcuts, see my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#_anonymous_functions

Answer (score 1):

If I read it all correctly the code above has a pattern similar to this:

```
// just a something

struct Blah {
    var stuffs : (message:String) -> Void

    init(closure:(message:String) -> Void) {
        self.stuffs = closure
    }
}

// an extension because the code above is also in an extension, but not needed at all
extension Blah {

// a function with a closure that also returns an instance of Self
    func spawnChild(closure:(message:String) -> Void) -> Blah {

        return Blah(closure: closure) // closure is passed to spawn

    }

}
```

Tests :

```
let alpha = Blah { (message) -> Void in
    print("alpha",message)
}

let beta = alpha.spawnChild { (message) -> Void in
    print("beta", message)
}

alpha.stuffs(message: "parrent") // alpha parent
beta.stuffs(message: "spawn") // beta spawn
```

Remember that the trailing closure is just syntactic sugar for an input parameter that is a closure. So anything that takes input parameters can have a trailing closure.